# EF Code First Foreign key must be mapped to some AssociationSet or EntitySets participating in a foreign key association on the conceptual side

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, code-first

we want to migrate our project from Database-First to Code-First.
For this task i used the Code First from database Generator from Visual Studio.
I have some tables with concatenated PKs and FKs.
I cannot change them to one simple "ID", because there is a legacy application that needs them this way.
The EF version is 6.1.3

When i start my programm, I'm getting the following error:

> (1568,10) : error 3015: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines
>   1568, 1583: Foreign key constraint
>   'tblRechnungPosition_tblAngebReches' from table tblAngebRech (RechNr,
>   RechPosNr, CompanyID) to table tblRechnungPosition (RechNr, CompanyID,
>   PosNr):: Insufficient mapping: Foreign key must be mapped to some
>   AssociationSet or EntitySets participating in a foreign key
>   association on the conceptual side.

I cannot figure out what is causing the error, for me all the relations seem to be correct.

Here are the classes:

```
public partial class tblAngebRech
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int AngebotID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int AngebPosNr { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int RechNr { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int RechPosNr { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 4)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public virtual tblAngebotPosition tblAngebotPosition { get; set; }

    public virtual tblRechnungPosition tblRechnungPosition { get; set; }
}
```

.

```
public partial class tblRechnungPosition
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public tblRechnungPosition()
    {
        tblAngebReches = new HashSet<tblAngebRech>();
        tblBeauftReches = new HashSet<tblBeauftRech>();
        tblRechPosMitarbs = new HashSet<tblRechPosMitarb>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int RechNr { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int PosNr { get; set; }

    public int PosTypID { get; set; }

    public int? StdKeyID { get; set; }

    public double Menge { get; set; }

    public double Betrag { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Bezeichnung { get; set; }

    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tblAngebRech> tblAngebReches { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tblBeauftRech> tblBeauftReches { get; set; }

    public virtual tblPositionstyp tblPositionstyp { get; set; }

    public virtual tblRechnung tblRechnung { get; set; }

    public virtual tblStundenKey tblStundenKey { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tblRechPosMitarb> tblRechPosMitarbs { get; set; }
```

And this is from `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<tblRechnungPosition>()
    .HasMany(e => e.tblAngebReches)
    .WithRequired(e => e.tblRechnungPosition)
    .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.RechNr, e.CompanyID, e.RechPosNr });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try to manually adjust the order of the FK properties in the modelbuilder to that:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<tblRechnungPosition>()
.HasMany(e => e.tblAngebReches)
.WithRequired(e => e.tblRechnungPosition)
.HasForeignKey(e => new { e.RechNr, e.RechPosNr, e.CompanyID });
```

I sent a bug issue to the EF 6.x Team at codeplex. 
Here is the link:https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2947

If that doesn't work. Try change the Order Number of the Column Attribute in class tblRechnungPosition to:

```
[Key]
[Column(Order = 0)]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int RechNr { get; set; }

[Key]
[Column(Order = 2)]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int CompanyID { get; set; }

[Key]
[Column(Order = 1)]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int PosNr { get; set; }
```

**Note:** You have composite foreign keys. In both table classes the order of the properties must be the same inside the `[Columns(Order = <order number>)]`.